# Set text in HTML paragraph from javascript function without formatting

Tags: javascript, html

How can I add text to a HTML paragraph without adding formatting to the inserted text? This is what I have so far:

```html
<p>Example paragraph <ins id="example"></ins>.</p>
<script>
  function getIt() {
    return "it"
  }
  document.getElementById("example").innerHTML = getIt();
</script>
```

When the word "it" is inserted, it is underlined. How dow I prevent it from being underlined?

Thank you!

Comment: Don't use the `<ins>` tag to prevent underline. Use a `<p>` or `<span>` tag instead. Or, you can change the style of the `<ins>` tag with CSS.

Comment: Also, your question is irrelevant to the title. Please fix.

Comment: You can show something like this here https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EwNbdg?editors=1111

Comment: @TyQ Thank you, this worked! Please review my title change and let me know if it needs to change. Please add your comment as an answer so I can mark it as accepted.

Comment: Go ahead and mark @YoungKyunJin's answer as correct as his method works just as well. Yes, your title is fine. Have a good day! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
ins{
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<p>Example paragraph <ins id="example"></ins>.</p>
<script>
  document.getElementById("example").style.textDecoration = "none";
  function getIt() {
          return "it"
  }
  document.getElementById("example").innerHTML = getIt();
</script>
```

You should set `text-decoration: none;`

Comment: He said in JavaScript so... `document.getElementById("example").style.textDecoration = "none";`

Answer (score 2):

This is because by default there there is text decoration underline in ins tag of html,you can override it by including the below css code in your head sect

```
<style>
ins { 
    text-decoration: none;
}
</style>
```